# Language Service Submit: Error '91'

Tags: excel, sas, vba

I followed the solution posted in below link to execute a simple SAS Query through VBA:
[Calling SAS through VBA](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Calling-SAS-through-VBA/td-p/79673)

```
Dim obObjectFactory As New SASObjectManager.ObjectFactory
Dim obObjectKeeper As New SASObjectManager.ObjectKeeper
Dim obServer As New SASObjectManager.ServerDef
Dim obSAS As SAS.Workspace
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
obServer.MachineDNSName = "xxxx@company.com"
obServer.Protocol = ProtocolBridge
obServer.Port = 8561
obObjectFactory.LogEnabled = True
Set obSAS = obObjectFactory.CreateObjectByServer("sas", False, obServer, "", "")
obSAS.LanguageService.Submit "PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE ME.TABLE1; RUN;" 'Error at submit
```

But I'm getting error at the above submit line as "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Link doesn't work

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: On the line I modified. The one posted in question

Comment: Ah! ok. You mentioned that, it just seems like an odd line to get that error. Try wrapping parantheses around the query string like `obSAS.LanguageService.Submit("Proc... whatnot... etc...;") and see if that fixes it up

Comment: Tried that.. Didn't work

Comment: Post the rest of your code

Comment: Please add the relevant code that you **actually** use by [edit]ing the original question.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Most probably `obSAS` was not set by the `CreateObjectByServer()` method. Try to do insert a `If obSAS Is Nothing Then ... Else ... End If` to confirm. Without documentation of SASObjectManager that is as far as we can help.

Comment: I believe you're right.. obSAS is Nothing. That explains the error.. but is there a way to solve this? @Dr Yunke

Comment: Post on communities.sas.com and the developers can help you out there.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an Asynchronous connection. I would try to create a syncronous connection instead (change second parameter to true).

```
Set obSAS = obObjectFactory.CreateObjectByServer("sas", True, obServer, "", "")
```

> Synchronous indicates whether a connection is synchronous or
>   asynchronous. The synchronous connection is most frequently used and
>   is the simplest connection to create. If this parameter equals TRUE,
>   CreateObjectByServer does not return until a connection is made. If
>   this parameter equals FALSE, the function returns a null value
>   immediately. When a connection is made, the object is stored in the
>   ObjectKeeper.

From SAS documentation. Thus why your variable is `Nothing` right away.

http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/dev_guide/dist-obj/winclnt/omcreate.html

Now for the Submit method, I suggest you add some error checking code like

```
If obSAS Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox("Connection failed")
Else
   obSAS.LanguageService.Submit "PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE ME.TABLE1; RUN;" 'Error at submit
End If
```

That above will answer your question of why you are getting the error *Object variable or With block variable not set*.

For the later **Run Time Error '-2147213310 (80042002)'** that is a different issue/question. And you should try to contact SAP tech support, with the information you provided there is nothing much we can do. The error must give you additional information in form of html tags. From the link you supplied, it seems this error is caused by a bad connection settings/parameters.

> The workspaceservers default port is **8591**. Perhaps the
>   workspaceserver also runs on a different machine. Connect to your
>   profile, go to the serverlist, locate the server you want to connect
>   to and right click the context menu "properties" to see the right
>   connection profile for your workspaceserver.
>
> BTW: if you are using IWA (integrated windows authentication) you must
>   not provide a username and password (Nothing).

```
Set obSAS = obObjectFactory.CreateObjectByServer("sas", True, obServer, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Comment: I tried that as well. When I use synchronous connection, it throws Automation Error. A window pops up with Run Time Error '-2147213310 (80042002)'

Comment: So you think that there is nothing wrong in my code? I did double checked the port number and  machine name etc using ITConfig2.exe and everything matches. I'll give a try with sas tech support